# Loading grunt tasks from a remote Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

In the root directory of a project, I'm trying to load Grunt tasks, and all the content of the file as well, from a remote Gruntfile.js, accessible through a network (web or internal network).

I've already tried several things (see below), first hosting the Gruntfile.js on a local Apache server for the tests.

**Using the `--gruntfile` option**

```
> /project/path> grunt --gruntfile=http://localhost/Gruntfile.js build
Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...ERROR
Fatal error: Unable to find "/project/path/http://localhost/Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile.
```

**Using the `--base` option**

```
> /project/path> grunt --base=http://localhost/Gruntfile.js build
    process.chdir(grunt.option('base') || path.dirname(gruntfile));
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
```

**Creating a Gruntfile.js located at the root directory of my project**, which contains only the following code :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadTasks( 'http://localhost/Gruntfile.js' );

};
```

The result was :

```
> /project/path> grunt build
>> Tasks directory "http://localhost/Gruntfile.js" not found.
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Another try with the Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require( 'http://localhost/Gruntfile.js' )( grunt );

};
```

Gave me this :

```
> /project/path> grunt build
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost/Gruntfile.js'
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

---

**Edit:** It seems there is no way of loading tasks from a grunt file not located on the disk. I will find another solution.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? I.e. maybe you're trying to use a hammer where a drill is needed?

Comment: I want to share a unique gruntfile.js between multiple projects maintained by multiple developers. The grunt tasks defined in this file must be accessible from every project root directory.

Comment: My recommendation: don't do it. You'll pull your hair out in a few months time. Better to use some kind of templating/file generator system to easily create them for each project. Better yet: drop grunt altogether. I've been using grunt from the very beginning and have been removing it from all my projects in the last year, bar a few exceptions. You almost never need it (since npm scripts are almost always enough)

Comment: Dropping grunt could be a solution. But I don't have the power to do that now. And I'm already pulling my hair out trying to keep the thirty gruntfile.js up-to-date when I make a change in the build tasks... I think I will make a custom grunt plugin with it, and add it as a devDependency of all my projects.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and this is my solution. I hope it helps someone in the present/future:

1. Create a npm package to host the Gruntfile.js and upload it to a repository (I´am currently using Bitbucket) This is how my package.json looks like:

   `{
     "name": "my-remote-gruntfile-package",
     "private": true,
     "version": "0.0.1"
   }`
2. Configure it in the package.json of your current project and install it using `npm install` or just run

   `npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:user/my-remote-gruntfile-package.git#0.0.1`
3. Create a bash script (or windows bash equivalent) to cover the problem of changing Gruntfile.js location and setting current base path. This is to avoid passing --gruntfile and --base parameters on every execution (this step is not mandatory)

   `#!/bin/bash
   grunt --base ./ --gruntfile ./node_modules/my-remote-gruntfile-package/GruntFile.js $1`

Note: take care of relative paths used on your Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

Requiring a separate file should work, note that you shouldn't refer to it via `localhost`, but rather the location on disk, for example `./somedir/yourtask.js`. Here's an example:

**yourtask.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    // your task config goes here
};
```

Your **Gruntfile.js**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var externalFile = require('./somedir/yourtask.js');

    grunt.initConfig({
        // some random tasks go here
        yourtask: externalFile
    });
};
```

This should work but I'm not able to run it right now and you haven't posted what kind of info you have defined in your separate file. You can also have a function in there as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But finding a way to access the file from http://localhost is the first purpose of my question. I don't want the Gruntfile.js to be located on my disk. I want it to be stored on a remote server, accessible through a network. I simply use a local Apache server for testing.

Comment: Then it becomes a bit more complicated since you'd have to download it, wait for it to download and then start Grunt. Not sure how possible that would be with out-of-the-box Grunt.